# Hadoop 2.6.x and Amazon AWS SDK Library conflicts http-core conflict

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services

My job writes each record to DynamoDB in the Hadoop's map.

I cannot make it run with Hadoop 2.6 which has  httpclient-4.2.5.jar and httpcore-4.2.5.jar.

AWS which I am using was built using httpclient-4.5.2.jar and httpcore-4.4.4.jar.

When I am using classpath to include the new jar files, it gives the following exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:49)
```

To me, it looks like Hadoop was built using the old libraries and something has changed in the syntax.

What's the reasonable solution than recompiling older sources of AWS?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update, I had to switch to Maven and play around with the versions a bit.

```
 <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netpreserve.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>webarchive-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally, it works